# OSM Leaflet Adding Ionic UI Component into bindPopup()

Tags: leaflet, ionic3, openstreetmap

Is there any way of showing ionic UI components such as ionic-button inside bindPopup function when we attached a popup to the marker in Leaflet.

data.elements.forEach(element => {
        this.markers.addLayer(L.marker(L.latLng(element.lat, element.lon), {
          icon: mIcon
        }).bindPopup("Button"));
      });
      this.map.addLayer(this.markers);